# How can I draw asynchronous to prevent blocking other UI actions?

Tags: c#, xaml, asynchronous, async-await

How can I draw asynchronous to prevent blocking other UI actions?
At this point I can't do anything while draw event is active.

Draw event

```
 private async void ca_Draw(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.ICanvasAnimatedControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasAnimatedDrawEventArgs args)
 {
     Draw(args.DrawingSession); 
 }
```

This method draw ellipses

```
public virtual void Draw(CanvasDrawingSession g)
{
     g.DrawEllipse(100, 100),10, 10, Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));
}
```

Comment: your ``Draw`` method needs to by async as well

Comment: You need to run Draw in the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke method which will  execute it asyncronously

Comment: I don't think you can, since drawing needs to run on the UI thread. If drawing is blocking your UI, it probably means you're drawing too much.